# What is the query to display data from 3 tables of mysql to JFrame?

Tags: java, mysql, database

My sql query is unable to show data of database tables into JFrame

I connect my database in phpMYAdmin from JFrame .I joined these three tables of database in my query and apply set and get Text in my code.

This is my Query in mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM agent AS a 
    INNER JOIN client AS c ON a.Agent_Id=c.Agent_Id 
    INNER JOIN policy AS p ON c.Policy_No=p.Policy_No
```

This is my code in Java

```
while(rs.next())
        {
            int Agent_Id = rs.getInt("Agent_Id");
            Agent_Id1.setText(String.valueOf(Agent_Id));

            String F_Name = rs.getString("F_Name");
            Agent_Name1.setText(F_Name);

            float Salary=rs.getFloat("Salary");
            Salary1.setText(String.valueOf(Salary));

            float Commission = rs.getFloat("Salary");
            Commission1.setText(String.valueOf(Salary*1.1));

            int Client_Id= rs.getInt("Client_Id");
            Client_Id1.setText(String.valueOf(Client_Id));

            int Policy_Id = rs.getInt("Policy_Id");
            Policy_Id1.setText(String.valueOf(Policy_Id));

        }
```

Column 'Client_Id' not found.

Column 'Policy_Id' not found.

It only gives the data from agent table. I want to show from all these tables.

Comment: Did you try to run this query to see if the field is actually there?

Comment: Yes, According to mapping rules Agent_Id and Policy_Id are foreign keys in table Client but in Agent table there are not any of  these foreign keys. So,I joined these tables but it can't work

Comment: Another thing, is better to return only the field you will use instead of using "select *"

Comment: You means like this  "SELECT a.Agent_Id, a.Agent_Name, a.Salary,(a.Salary*1.1) as Commission, c.Client_Id ,p.Policy_Id FROM agent AS a INNER JOIN client AS c ON a.Agent_Id=c.Agent_Id INNER JOIN policy AS p ON c.Policy_No=p.Policy_No "